# Rewrite labels on fields rendered via php

Tags: 7, entities, display-suite

So I'm designing a specific node page where I'm manually inserting every field (to ensure I can customize it as the client wants) and I'm having a bit of trouble with certain areas.

Essentially I'm curious if there's a way to rewrite the label of a field while I'm including/rendering it.. see the code below for what I'm currently using:

```
<?php print render($content['field_product_reference']); ?>
```

I should also mention that I'm using Drupal 7 & the DisplaySuite module.

**UPDATE: Is it possible to make it display HTML in the title area?**

Comment: when you say you are manually inserting every field, are you writing a custom node template file ?

Comment: Yes I've got a separate .tpl.php file for this node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is usually in the `#title` key in each content member of the array, so something like

```
$content['field_product_reference']['#title'] = t('Something new');
print render($content['field_product_reference']);
```

should update it.

If not, try installing the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and running `dpm($content['field_product_reference']);` to see whereabouts in the array the label value is.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I did have the devel module installed I just wasn't sure how to rewrite the title area. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a possibility to display HTML instead of just text? I'm trying to rewrite one of my titles/labels to display as a FontAwesome icon.

Comment: I think the title goes through `check_plain()` so it'll get escaped. You could always try setting `'#title_display' => 'hidden'` to remove the title and adding `'#prefix' => '<div>some html</div>'`, it'll probably have the same effect